# Adding a user with random password on debian 7 (fabric)

Tags: python, linux, debian, shadow, fabric

I want to create a new user with a random password on debian 7 with fabric.

The fabfile looks like this:

```
import hashlib
import string
import random

def new_user(user):
    passwd = random_pass()
    passwd_sha512 = "%s" % hashlib.sha512(passwd).hexdigest()
    sudo("useradd %s --password %s" % (user, passwd_sha512))


def random_pass(size=30, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
```

Whats wrong here? Blocksize? The type of encryption (`$6$` for sha512) is also missing in `/etc/shadow`.

I tried to add it to the parameter with `--password $6$%s`.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Print out your command before invoking it with sudo(). If you can copy/paste the printed password and run THAT, then it is an escaping issue as umläute suggests. But...

I would avoid trying to craft a workaround using something else, like subprocess, without first fully understanding the failure.

First confirm that what fails in Fabric also fails on the command line directly. Also, I would assume that at least "some" characters are never valid for a password. You should research what is acceptable password chars and then account for that inside of random_pass.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [crypt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) module better suited to calculating the encrypted password.

Answer (score 0):

your password might contain "weird" characters, that will make the actual cmd-string not what you expect. you might have more success using `subprocess.call` (with string-arrays) rather than a single string.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sudo',
                 'useradd',
                 '--password', passwd_sha512,
                 user])
```